# Android Studio - Support package

Tags: android, android-studio, bundle

Android Studio does not provide me all methods of the "Bundle"-class.

When I want to use .getString(), it shows me as an error. I have no clue why !?!?!

That is my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "test.android.com.test"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':facebook')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:20.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.42'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.6'
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have the right `import` statement? Perhaps you are pulling in some class named `Bundle` other than the one that you expect.

Comment: Yes, I am using the correct import. import android.os.Bundle;

Comment: What is the specific error message that you are getting?

Comment: Error message by IDE is: "Cannot resolve method getString(....)" or "Cannot resolve method putString(....)"

For Strings, it provides me... ex. "putCharSequence(....)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution. If someone has the same problem here you go.

Change from:

```
compileSdkVersion 20
buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"
```

Change to:

```
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"
```